# How can I fork an existing blockchain and limit token creation (if possible)?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, erc20

I was thinking of forking an existing blockchain implementation (irrelevant for the matter) but would like to know if it's possible to only allow my tokens to be used on that blockchain.

Is that even possible? If so, how could I achieve it?
Because, for example, if you use the Ethereum or QTUM blockchains I think all ERC20 or QRC20 contracts can be deployed there, which I don't want.

Or do I have to create my blockchain from scratch?

Thank you!

Comment: It's important to realize what these tokens really are - smart contracts typically containing mapping (though they could be arguably implemented using other data structures too). So by saying you don't want tokens on your blockchain, you are basically saying you don't want smart contracts. In case of ERC20 tokens, it's smart contracts with a specific interface. Is that what you want? I think there are probably many blockchain implementations to be found on GitHub, which doesn't have smart contracts.

Answer (score 0):

If that blockchain supports smart contracts (as Ethereum or Qtum) I would say **No**.

Smart contracts allow people to do "whatever" they want.

Even if by absurd, you (in someway) could prevent people from implementing the ER/QRC20 interface they would still be able achieve the same functionality in many different ways.

Remember that in the end your blockchain is fueled with its own coin, your coin, not the ER/QRC20 tokens.